# Windows 7: folders' taskbar icons issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons

I compressed the files on my System drive to gain some space, and now my folders icon looks like this in the taskbar:

[image]

I ***KNOW*** there is a very easy way to set this icon back to normal, since it already happened to me once a while ago, but I can't remember what it was...?!

thanks!

**[EDIT]** Deleting the IconCache.db file solved the issue:

1. Open Windows Explorer, and configure your Folder Options > Views to show Hidden / System Files
2. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Local folder
3. Delete the hidden IconCache.db file
4. Reboot

I knew it was easy!

Comment: Did you try to rebuild icon cache? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

Comment: I posted the solution you found as a community wiki so other users can easily find the answer (in case they don't read the whole question and skip straight down to the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the IconCache.db file solved the issue:

1. Open Windows Explorer, and configure your Folder Options > Views to show Hidden / System Files
2. Go to C:\Users\< User >\AppData\Local folder
3. Delete the hidden IconCache.db file
4. Reboot